# How to use UIApplication handleOpenURL Notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, uiapplication, url-scheme

I am trying to handle UIApplication Notifications to get URL Schemes in current open view. I have tried several notifications but i don't know which object contains the URL Schemes.

```
 NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    //[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(DocumentToDropboxDelegate) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(DocumentToDropboxDelegate) name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object:nil];
```

Can someone pelase help me with this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Mike K mentioned you'll have to implement one (or both) of the following methods:

```
- application:handleOpenURL:
- application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
```

on your UIApplicationDelegate. There is no matching notification for them.

Example below:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
        [self.viewController handleOpenURL:url];
    }
    return YES;
}

//Deprecated
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
        [self.viewController handleOpenURL:url];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou m0rt1m3r, I know you are on the rite solution but i have one more problem. The problem is i need URL in the current open view. Can i check which view is currently open?

Comment: Try to check your view's window property. It should be not-nil: if (viewController.view.window) { /* view visible*/ }

Comment: Apple says 'application:handleOpenURL:' is deprecated, to use 'application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:' instead

Answer (score 2):

`application:handleOpenURL:` is called on your application delegate - not via a NSNotification. the preferred delegate method to implement is: `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`.

more info can be found here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleOpenURL:

Comment: Thankyou for your reply i know about UIApplication delegate, What i am looking for is a notification with that i can get returned NSURL of URL Schemes.

Comment: How would I know which viewController is currently opened? So I can pass the URL to