# Launching app from custom urlscheme

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am developing an iPhone app that can be launching via a link to a custom URL scheme from an email.

When the app is launched from the email, I want to populate a text box with an order number that is appended to the launching URL `(appname:\\?orderno=1234)`. I can launch the app from the URL fine.

My problem is extracting the `orderno` variable from the URL and adding the value to the textbox. I have achieved it with preferences but it only shows the value, the second time the app is launched. How can I extract the variable in the `Appdelegate` and then allow it for use in the view controller.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing -handleOpenUrl: in your applicationDelegate?

See also this question:
[How to use UIApplication handleOpenURL Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000179/how-to-use-uiapplication-handleopenurl-notifications)

Comment: Yeah all that part of the app works fine. It's just what method should I use to store a variable when the app launches so that I have access to it when the view is drawn as from what I can tell the screen is drawn before I can access the "orderno" variable.